# Show and update Table with data from AJAX call using WebSocket

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I trying to show and update data in table in PartialView. My solution doesn't work.

## This is my View scrap Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Exchange.WebUI.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webSocket;
    function webSocketResults() {
        webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://....");
        webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            showCurrenciesData(event.data);
            $("#webSocketValue").text(event.data);
        };
    }
    function showCurrenciesData(data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("getWebSocketResults", "Home")",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#currenciesTable").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError, xhr, ajaxOptions);
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = webSocketResults;
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 well well-sm">
        <h2>Currencies</h2>
        <hr>
            @Html.Partial("_CurrenciesTable", Model)
    </div>....
```

## Partial View _CurrenciesTable.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Exchange.WebUI.Models.Item>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_CurrenciesTable";
}
<div id="currenciesTable">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.code)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.unit)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.purchasePrice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sellPrice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.averagePrice)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.code)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.unit)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.purchasePrice)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sellPrice)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.averagePrice)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        No Connection:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
</table>
</div>
```

## And There is Controller HomeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult getWebSocketResults(CurrenciesViewModel currencies)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
            return PartialView("_CurrenciesTable", currencies.items);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(currencies.items);
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I see data from ajax in controller and in partial view during the debugging, but table is still empty.

## Screens from testing

First is debigging partial view, Second is Table, Third is error from ajax errof function - i don't understand this error
[image: Debugging PartialView - data is here]

[image: And the home page looks like this]

[image: This is error from ajax error function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `dataType: 'json'` with `dataType: 'html'` in the ajax call.

Comment: It Works ! Thank You Very Much!